# Find and extract a string of exactly 'n' successive contiguous digits from an alphanumeric string

Tags: regex

Given an arbitrary alphanumeric string:

`The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over 987654321, on his second try.`

can regex extract the string of contiguous numbers which is exactly nine-digits in length if there are other numbers in the string which are longer than nine digits?

That is, get  `987654321` and ignore `12345678901234`?

The rule would be "get any string of digits nine characters long, which is either unbounded, or if bounded, is bounded by any character other than 0-9."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches your target *only* (no need to sully yourself with groups):

```
(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/TJTIvxp0uN).

This uses look arounds to assert "number boundaries" either end. Look arounds don't consume anything, so the characters either side are not part of the match - only your target number is matched.

Further, by using *negative* look arounds for a *digit*, rather than *positive* look arounds for a *non* digit, the boundaries also match start/end of input - so 9-digit numbers at the very start or very end of the input still match.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The simplicity seems elegant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

```
\b\d{9}\b
# a word boundary (ie space, punctuation, comma)
# exactly nine consecutive digits
# another boundary
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rP5iH3/1).

---

To provide another example:

```
\D(\d{9})\D
# not a digit
# nine consecutive digits
# not a digit
```

With [**this one**](https://regex101.com/r/rP5iH3/3), you'll need to use `$1` again. It depends on where the digits are, though. The latter won't work at the very start or beginning of the string (it requires **exactly one** character on each side). Your best bet for digits on their own is `\b`.

Comment: But it says nothing matched. I don't understand "This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string"

Comment: @Tim: No, it said, no matching group extracted - you need parentheses to show them: https://regex101.com/r/rP5iH3/2 But, depending on the programming language used, simply use `$0` with the first and `$1` with the second pattern. Parentheses form a **capturing group**.

Comment: OK. Thanks very much. I didn't realize the power of `\b` I can accept in 7 minutes :)

Comment: @Tim: No worries, glad to help.

Comment: @Tim: Added another example in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't handle the "unbounded" scenario, e.g. the string begins or ends with the nine-digit number.

Comment: @Tim: But `\b` does, have added an instruction.

Comment: fails to extract last digit on `The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over 987654321`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Not true, copy your sentence into regex101 and see that it matches the first expression.

Comment: @Jan: `\D(\d{9})\D` fails when 9 digits are in the end: https://regex101.com/r/sB8wQ2/1. `\b(\d{9})\b` works only if boundaries are non-letters.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Please read the **second half** of my answer - and `\b` also works if it is the start or end.

Comment: @Jan so which one is your solution in the end? both of them have problems depending on the string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I would go for the `\b` solution which - in my opinion covers almost every possible scenario but it is not always supported.

Comment: `p=re.compile(r"\b\d{9}\b")
print(re.findall(p,"The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over 987654321dd, 123456789"))` => only matches ['123456789'] because there are letters after the first 9-digit group. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\b` to bound the string does not work for `The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over xx987654321xx, on his second try` (bounded by non-digits), that does:

```
(?:^|[^\d])(\d{9})(?:$|[^\d])
```

(non-capturing groups for start/end or non-digit)

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yU2bL3/1)

Edit: simpler more "modern" style:

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{9})(?:$|\D)
```

Python test (which captures several 9-digit groups):

```
import re
p=re.compile(r"(?:^|\D)(\d{9})(?:$|\D)")
print(re.findall(p,"The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over 987654321dd, 123456789"))
```

gives:

```
['987654321', '123456789']
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. I know too little about regex to judge it on elegance, but you have my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. the "modern" one is better (but I just learned about `\D` honestly :))

Comment: But shouldn't it capture *all* nine-digit sequences per the OP? I don't think string "The quick brown 12345678901234 fox jumped over xx987654321, on his second try 353134334 ." works (last 9-digit sequence not captured).

Comment: you're right about that on the site but in python with `re.findall` it works fine.